# How can I make a simple form application in Visual Studio that writes commands into a cmd.exe prompt?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, button, cmd

I am a novice when it comes to Visual Studio 2012 and programming in general, but I am curious to learn to more in Computer Science. I am currently working on an application that allows me to click a button that will run a command in a command line server that I am running. The main idea of the application is to create a GUI that allows users to enter preset commands by clicking buttons in the application. I am using the VB language.

For example: To start my server I created a "Start Server" button that opens up a batch file to execute a few commands to get my server started. - Is there a way to bypass the batch file to execute these commands?

Also say I wanted to create a second "Stop Server" button that wrote and executed the command "stop" into the command prompt. Is there a way to do this?

Finally I wanted to have the command prompt run in the background, or within the app, so that users cannot write in their own custom commands. How can I do this? Or is this not possible?

I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to open command prompt and execute commands from vb.net

```
Process.Start("cmd", "Your Code to execute")
```

Updates made as per request?

store the commands to be executed in an array as follows

```
Dim cmdarray() as string={"cmd1","cmd2","cmd3","cmd4","cmd5"}
for i as integer=0 to cmdarray.length-1
Process.Start("cmd", cmdarray(i))
next i
```

Comment: How can I execute multiple lines of code? I would like to eliminate using a batch program to execute multiple lines of code if I can. I tried creating multiple commands and combining them like this: `Shell("cmd /k" & setpath, Command1, Command3, Command4)` This did not seem to work though.

Comment: @Allen i have put the code in my answer how you can execute multiple lines of code.

Comment: @Sujith How do I write lines to the command prompt after a window has been opened? I am assuming I have to create a new process?

Answer (score 0):

Change the command to what you want to execute.
The /k in Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True) will ceep the windows open after the command is executed.
Change /k to /c to make it close after the command is executes.

```
    Private Sub CmdIpConfigAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CmdIpConfigAll.Click
    Dim Command As String
    Command = "ipconfig /all"
    Shell("cmd /k" & Command, 1, True)
    End Sub
```

To execute more commands at ones you could use.
When command 1 is finished he will start with command 2 and so on.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Command0 As String
    Dim Command1 As String
    Dim Command2 As String
    Dim Command3 As String

    Command0 = "ipconfig /all"
    Command1 = "netstat -a"
    Command2 = "net user"
    Command3 = "ping www.google.com"

    Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k {0} & {1} & {2} & {3}", Command0, Command1, Command2, Command3))

End Sub
```

Comment: This works to allow my program to execute code in cmd but it opens up a new window every time I press a button. I need the code to be executed in the same prompt.